# Is this circuit correct? Set a digital input low

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, bjt

When input becomes high (24V) or low (ground,) I want digital pin1 connect to ground. I designed this. Is it correct and safe for use in a car with a car battery?

I want digital pin swapped between unconnected and grounded. So:

1. If Input = High --- > DP1=ground
2. If input=Low -------> DP1=ground
3. If input=Unconnected ------->DP=unconnected

It’s designed to detect car's door opened / closed in different car systems.

[image]

My new solution: I use a switch so thr user can select input, ground or Vcc.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If the digital pin should be grounded in both situations, just tie it directly to ground.

Comment: @Mat Its connected to cars door . In some cars input is vcc some cars gnd... I want to response to different input correctly

Comment: Tip: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor sorry i cant access to my pc for saving files for some reason ...

Comment: @Mat, I think the OP wants to design a microcontroller interface to work with any 12 - 24 V vehicle door system and detect door open (switch contacts closing) for either positive switching or ground switching. (Some will have the switch in the positive wire and some will connect the switch wire to ground when door is opened.) OP wants it to work with either without having to reconfigure.

Comment: If the door switch grounds the signal, I suspect that the car circuit will pull the signal toward the positive supply when the switch is open, and vice-versa if the door switch connects to +, so you will have difficulty distinguishing the "not connected" state.

Comment: @yeg, you don't need to save CircuitLab screens to your PC and upload them. Start CircuitLab with the button on the editor toolbar and use "Save and Insert" when finished.

Comment: @Transistor ok thank you i didnt know its great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your requirements is this:

```
Vin            Logic out
------------------------
V+             0
GND            0
Open-circuit   1
```

I don't think your idea will work. When the switch is open the output of the switch does not float. It will be pulled high or low by the lightbulb or door monitoring circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKQHGV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) With a positive switching circuit the lamp or monitoring circuit will pull the signal line to ground. (b) With the more common traditional negative switching circuit the signal line will be pulled high by the lamp or monitoring circuit.*

You're going to have to use either a switch to make the device configurable by the user or somehow set an option in the software.

Alternatively you need to disconnect everything from the switches to that they only connect to your system.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIa9i8.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. With the addition of a polarity selection switch the circuit becomes simple.*

A bi-directional opto-coupler allows easy monitoring of the door switch(es) and provides electrical isolation for the microcontroller.

---

If the switch wire is only connected to the microcontroller then you could do this easily using analog inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDLqy7.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. A window comparator circuit.*

- R1 and R2 bias the switch wire to V+/2.
- R3, 4 and 5 set window thresholds of 1/4 V+ and 3/4 V+.
- The comparators have open-collector outputs. If either switches low the digital output will be pulled low. (You need a pull-up somewhere in that line.)
- If V<sub>SWITCH</sub> < 3 V then CMP2 switches the output low.
- If V<sub>SWITCH</sub> > 9 V then CMP1 switches the output low.
- Otherwise output switches high.

I chose the R3, R4 and R5 values to make it obvious what the divider tap-off points would be. (It's 1 kΩ per volt.) You can scale these up to reduce current draw.

Comment: Input directly going to MCU so i thing look at this as switch is  wrong .... Because i want set digital pin low or unconnected then with programming i detect situation of door .

Comment: i think i have to using a switch . i add a new solution. what you think ? also about resistor value selection .

Answer (score 2):

For "more than" you can also use resistor devider with high resistances to drain the battery less (but you will not reach a "sharp" cut).

R5 is no needed in your case, just short it.

[image]

[image]

Green is input voltage, blue the digital_pin state

**Edit:**

According your edits to unaffect the pin state when input is disconnected (floating) you can try this. (I am not 100 percent sure about quality but simulation works).
The base of PNP is tied to 5v Vcc during Vin disconnection so it is off and Q3 is also off (pin state stays high).
[image]

Comment: could you add more description which how this circuit works when input is high ,low and unconnected . Thank you

Comment: 1) When the Vin is more than 18.0v (zener voltage) a voltage appears across R2, what opens Q1 and pull digital pin to ground. 2)When the Vin falls below 5v a voltage across R4 is less then 0.7v so Q2 is turned off what couses opening of Q3 so dig. pin is pulled again. When Vin is disconnected the 2) is valid again.

Comment: your design is great but i want digital pin swip between unconnected and grounded . So if 1)Input = High --- >DP1=ground ......... 2) if input=Low ------->DP=ground ....3)if input=Unconnected ------->DP=unconnected....

Comment: i design new circuit in my question. What is you idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not looking great - if the input is grounded then D2 and Q2 will both present a diode drop and so DigitalPin1 won’t pull below about 1.2V.  If the input is high then Q1 will pull the output down more effectively.  If the input is open circuit then some current will flow Q2 R4 D2 R2 R3 GND and so DigitalPin1 will still be pulled down somewhat.  Michal’s circuit would be better, a couple of comparators and a logic gate better again.

Comment: i design new circuit in my question. What is you idea ?

Comment: Your new circuit is a little better but I still have concerns: it will draw 24mA when 24 V is applied, when 0V is applied it has a 50k pull-down which seems rather high, and when 24 is applied there will be a momentary 24V applied to the IO pin until the transistor switches on.